# How to change the position of the web part in single zone?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have created the SharePoint web part zone in custom page layout.Also added one custom web part into the zone using PowerShell script.Then I need to add the another list manually into the same zone.If I add the list manually it will add into the top of the zone.Instead of doing this the list need to appear in the bottom of the web part.is it possible to do? suggest an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the list view web part, After adding the web part, edit the web part, change the Zone Index to 1 and save the changes. And save the page.

Your list view web part will be at second position.

Set zone index of your custom web part to **0** and for list view web part set it to **1**.

[image]

The Other Approach is that you can just drag and drop the web parts to arrange the web parts.

Comment: You can also drag and drop the web parts (might depend on the type of page).

Comment: drag and drop is not working